# Steam VR Scene stops responding on reload in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, steamvr

I have a scene that I'm working on using Steam VR 2.0, and Unity 2018.3.2f1. I have a simple statement in it that reloads the scene

```
private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
        {
            SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("Final");
        }
    }
```

The issue is: when I reload the scene, it stops responding properly. I am still able to move my head around, and hover over objects. And the objects I hover over get highlighted, but **they stay highlighted**. I'm not able to pick them up, or interact with them in any meaningful way, and I don't know why this is happening.

I've attached a screenshot of the issue below.

As you can see, multiple objects are highlighted, and the hand mesh is weird:

[image]

Solutions I've tried--

- Using LoadScene instead of LoadSceneAsync
- Using Application.LoadScene instead
- Tried to edit the Player script in SteamVR library to not add it to `Don't Destroy On Load`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please don't add `Solved` to the title or answer your question in the question itself. Instead add a proper answer and Mark it as accepted after two days. On this way people can see your question is solved and future users can find it better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was arising because the Player prefab in SteamVR 2.0 had `Do Not Destroy` on Load checked. So, there were multiple players being instanced when I reloaded the scene. I unchecked that box, and now everything is in order.

The checkbox is located inside the `[SteamVR]` object under the `Player` prefab: [image: The checkbox is located inside the <code>[SteamVR]</code> object under the <code>Player</code> prefab]